# How to do a curl request in Swift?

Tags: swift, http, curl, request

that is my curl code

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
-u keyAuth: \
-d country=US \
-d type=custom \
-d requested_capabilities[]=card_payments
```

and i need to do it in Swift.
I tried with this

```
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts"),
        let payload = "{\"country\":\"US\",\"type\":\"custom\",\"requested_capabilities[]\":\"card_payments\"}".data(using: .utf8) else
    {
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("keyAuth", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpBody = payload

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
        guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

        if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(str)
        }
        }.resume()
```

But this doesn't work, my error message is `You did not provide an API key, though you did set your Authorization header. Using Bearer auth, your Authorization header should look something like 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'` How I can solve it? Cause I think it is possible to perform curl request in Swift

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using Stripe's swift library? https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: Yes, cause I can't do everything in this SDK

Comment: `request.addValue("Bearer \(yourApiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`

Comment: Your curl command is working, what is the authentication format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the array parameter `requested_capabilities`.
Whe using JSON, you don't suffix the square bracktes to the key ( `requested_capabilities[]`) like in curl. Instead, you write the value(s) in square brackets, like here:

```
let payload =  "{\"country\":\"US\",\"type\":\"custom\",\"requested_capabilities\":[\"card_payments\"]}"
```

or, more readable:

```
let payload = """
                {
                    "country" : "US",
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "requested_capabilities" : ["card_payments"]
                }
"""
```

Nevertheless, if you are using hard-coded JSON and maybe want to insert some variable data into the structure, be very careful to prevent [Bobby-Tables-Attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I used curl to JSON converter and copy the result into the payload. So this is my result: 
`let payload = """
                {

                    "country" : "US",
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "requested_capabilities" : ["card_payments"],
                    "auth": {"user": "authKey","password":""}
                }
            """.data(using: .utf8)`
But error message is the same ;/ You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header

Comment: Oh, i fixed it. I changed `request.addValue("keyAuth", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` to `request.addValue("Bearer \(secretKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`